# Shortest path in a custom binary search tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree, graph-theory

## This a question from a coding competition

The original question can be found here http://www.olympiad.org.za/olympiad/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/2013-PO-Question-Paper.pdf
Question 5

SHORTEST PATH THROUGH THE HALL
[by Alan Smithee of Hulsbos High]

The hall is packed wall to wall with rows of chairs,
but in each row there are exactly two chairs
missing. The chairs in each row have numbers
from 1 to 100. Write a program that will calculate
the length of the shortest path from the front to the
back of the hall.
Each chair is 1 unit wide and each row is 1 unit
deep (from the front of a chair to the front of the
chair behind it). It is not possible to move
diagonally. You may start in front of any gap in the
front row and end behind any gap in the last row.
You always walk through the middle of a gap.
Illustrated is the shortest path through a hall, with
five rows of chairs. In the illustration the hall is
only 10 chairs wide instead of 100.
The first number in the input will contain the
number n – the number of rows. The next n lines
will have two numbers, separated by a space,
indicating where the gaps are.
Example
Input:
5
3 6
2 8
4 5
7 8
3 10

I think I have an efficient algorithm that I think will work, but I'm not sure how to implement it into Java.

What I want to do is break up each choice into a search tree so for instance if the user input was:

number of rows: 3

Spaces : 4 7 
         2 9
         8 11

Make 2 search trees:

```
              4                               7            
       2           9                     2           9
     8   11      8   11             8      11     8      11
```

And then find  the path where the difference between each node is the smallest 
So in this case the shortest path would be in the second tree 7->9->8 with the total distance being 5 (||7-9|-8|)
So my question is then

1. Is this acceptable algorithm given the problem
2. How would I implement either this algorithm or another in java

@JuanLopes
Take for instance this example (0s represent a space).

Row6: 0 2 3 4 5 6 0 8 9

Row5: 0 2 3 4 5 6 0 8 9

Row4: 1 2 3 0 5 6 0 8 9

Row3: 1 2 3 0 5 6 0 8 9

Row2: 1 2 3 0 5 6 0 8 9

Row1: 1 2 3 0 5 6 0 8 9

What I understand from your algorithm is that it looks at each row individually. So through rows 1-4 the distance between each space to the next row is equal but when you get to row 5 if you went down the path where all the 4s were missing it would take you longer compared to going down the path with all the 7s missing, does your solution take that into account?

Comment: Actually, the answer for the example you gave is 6, not 5. (7 to 9 = 2) + (9 to 8 = 1) + 3 rows = 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you described is not acceptable because there can be at most 100 rows, so if in each row the number of nodes in the tree doubles, you'll end up with 2^101 nodes in your tree in the worst case.

That problem can be solved by a simple dynamic programming, where on each step you have to choose the minimum between the first and the second gap:

```
T(0, j) = 1
T(i, j) = 1+min(
              abs(pos(i, j)-pos(i-1, 0)) + T(i-1, 0),
              abs(pos(i, j)-pos(i-1, 1)) + T(i-1, 1))
```

Where `i` is the `i`th  row and `j` is either `0` or `1`, denoting which gap we chose on the last turn. Here is some example Java implementation:

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import static java.lang.Math.min;

public class Main {
    public static int solve(int[][] P) {
        int a = 1, b = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < P.length; i++) {
            int na = 1 + min(
                    abs(P[i][0] - P[i - 1][0]) + a,
                    abs(P[i][0] - P[i - 1][1]) + b);

            int nb = 1 + min(
                    abs(P[i][1] - P[i - 1][0]) + a,
                    abs(P[i][1] - P[i - 1][1]) + b);

            a = na;
            b = nb;
        }
        return min(a, b);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(solve(new int[][]{
                {3, 6},
                {2, 8},
                {4, 5},
                {7, 8},
                {3, 10},
        }));


        System.out.println(solve(new int[][]{
                {4, 7},
                {2, 9},
                {8, 11}
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so your right about that algorithm being inefficient but I'm fairly sure this algorithm wont work 100% of the time. Take for instance if you have equal distances between spaces for 10 rows on the 11th row it changes if you go down the wrong path it will take you longer in that scenario, because the algorithm only looks at the next step and not the nth step

Comment: Can you elaborate on this example? I'm confident this algorithm solves the problem. Not because I trust myself that much, but because this is a classic dynamic programming problem. But  I can only be sure if I test it with the contest data: do you know where to find it?

Comment: Please see the revisions to the question :D

Comment: @TamirShklaz Yes, it takes. If you look closely, the algorithm does not choose a path to take. Instead it computes the minimum of choosing both options in each row coming from both options in the previous row. Btw, the answer in your example is 6 again.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you very much, do you know of any good guides which I can use to further learn dynamic programming

Comment: @TamirShklaz The best way to learn is to solve many DP problems. There is a section in the [Halim brothers' book](https://sites.google.com/site/stevenhalim/) about it.

Comment: @TamirShklaz Btw, if the algorithm solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted :)